# How to display images in a list view?

Tags: c#

My knowledge is stored in sql server eg a sample of the data in the list view show like this, I wrote:

```
item.SubItems.Add(dr["Fname"].ToString ());
```

A statement that I wrote when I was on the field list, click on the text box was shown Vaio example:

```
Vfname.Text = e.Item.SubItems[1].Text;
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what you've tried so far and what you'd like to achieve - I don't really understand from your description what you did and what doesn't work, it's quite confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are trying to do, but I assume you should add Image objects to your List View, using System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(), then draw them calling Graphics.DrawImage, passing the image file you have in the listview.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42807xh1(v=vs.110).aspx

```
   Image newImage = Image.FromFile("SampImag.jpg");

    // Create Point for upper-left corner of image.
    Point ulCorner = new Point(100, 100);

    // Draw image to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, ulCorner);
```